# Can't add String variable to my manifest

Tags: gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file and I want to insert some variables into my manifest. This is what I have

```
def dateformat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd")
version = dateformat.format(new Date());
int userlimit = System.properties['user.limit'] == null ? 1 : System.properties['user.limit'] as int
def owner = System.properties['owner'] == null ? 'Demo version' : System.properties['owner']

task release(dependsOn: [jar, libs, obfuscate]) {
  doLast {
      def classesDir = new File('expanded-libs')
      classesDir.mkdir()

      configurations.embed.each { 
        println "Unzipping $it to expanded-libs.."
        ant.unzip(src: it, dest: 'expanded-libs')
      }

      task combinedJar(type: Jar) {
        from zipTree('build/foo-bar-pg-' + version + '.jar')
        from configurations.embed.collect { println "Adding $it to the fat jar"; zipTree(it) }
        archiveName "../foo-bar-${version}${outputFileNameSuffix}.jar";
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
        duplicatesStrategy 'EXCLUDE'
        manifest {
          attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Foo Bar Module', 'Implementation-Version': version, 'User-Limit': userlimit, 'Licensed-To': owner
        }
      }
      combinedJar.execute()
  }
}
```

Now the interesting thing is that it works without the `'Licensed-To': owner` piece, but somehow I can't use that variable in the manifest. For integers, it works, but owner is a String.

This is the error message I get if I run `gradle release -Downer="foo" -Duserlimit=20`

```
* What went wrong:
   Execution failed for task ':release'.
   > Could not find method task() for arguments [{type=class org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar}, combinedJar, build_36jmpdf
2mspiolilq5o7ipbd86$_run_closure14_closure27_closure29@547a8dfd] on task ':release'.
```

Can anyone help me how could I put String typed JVM arguments into my manifest?

Comment: Ok, so I solved this by directly using `System.properties['owner']` in the `manifest`, and setting that to `Demo version` if none was specified. So the question is now more about understanding the reason, not solving the problem.

Comment: Both declaring a task in `doLast` and calling a task's `execute` method is not supported.

Comment: Thanks, I am beginner with gradle and did not find any other way to do what I wanted. Anyways, the issue is the same if I move it outside..

Comment: That's why I wrote this as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a closing } brace after the manifest attributes.

Comment: Thanks, that was just a copy-paste issue, not the real problem